# Excel sheet corrupted after conditional formatting

Tags: phpexcel

I am generating an excel sheet with phpexcel, when using conditional formatting with the condition being (search for a text or part of it), i get a validation error when trying to open the generated sheet. Works perfectly with numbers, Less so WITH TEXTS.

Here is my code :

```
 //conditional formatting
  $objConditional1 = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional();
  $objConditional1->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CONTAINSTEXT)
            ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_CONTAINSTEXT)
            ->addCondition('X');
 $objConditional1->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_YELLOW);

  $objConditional3 = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional();
  $objConditional3->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS)
            ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_GREATERTHANOREQUAL)
            ->addCondition('0');
  $objConditional3->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_GREEN);


$conditionalStyles = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getConditionalStyles();
array_push($conditionalStyles, $objConditional3);
array_push($conditionalStyles, $objConditional1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->setConditionalStyles($conditionalStyles);
```

Does any one know how to work around this ? am i doing anything wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: any soln for this issue? I am getting same issue

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, though i have not tested with your case specifically, when you try to apply conditional formatting based on CONTAINSTEXT,
you shouldn't call

```
'->addCondition('X')'
```

(line 5 in your code), but instead call the method:

```
->setText('X')
```

On your PHPExcel_Style_Conditional objects. This is how I specify the text to compare to in my PHPExcel sheets.

Comment: Thanks @devplayer this works for me. How can I get the Text value from other row cell?

Comment: i think that instead of 
->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CONTAINSTEXT);
, you need to set it to an expression:
      ->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_EXPRESSION)->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL)
                ->addCondition('AND((B2<>B3),B2<>"")');

(taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652458/phpexcel-conditional-formatting-not-quite-right )