# PHPExcel conditional formatting not quite right

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to add a border to the bottom of all cells in every row after row 2 that satisfies this condition:

```
$objConditional1 = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional();
$objConditional1->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_EXPRESSION)
                ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL)
                ->addCondition('AND((B2<>B3),B2<>"")');
$objConditional1->getStyle()->getBorders()->getBottom()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);  

$conditionalStyles = $sheet->getStyle('B2')->getConditionalStyles();
array_push($conditionalStyles, $objConditional1);    
$sheet->getStyle('B2')->setConditionalStyles($conditionalStyles);

$sheet->duplicateConditionalStyle(
$sheet->getStyle('B2')->getConditionalStyles(),
    'B3:B9999'
);
```

1. I'm not sure I understand how to add this condition to every single row and column after row 2...
2. Second of all, the border is not being added as expected... In excel the formatting says (none)...

Can I have some help with this?

The goal is to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The addition is in the last line! Did the job.. ta da

```
$objConditional1 = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional();
$objConditional1->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_EXPRESSION)
                ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL)
                ->addCondition('AND((B2<>B3),B2<>"")');
$objConditional1->getStyle()->getBorders()->getBottom()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);  

$conditionalStyles = $sheet->getStyle('B2')->getConditionalStyles();
array_push($conditionalStyles, $objConditional1);    
$sheet->getStyle('A$2:$U$10000')->setConditionalStyles($conditionalStyles);
```